# How to create a bilingual book where part, chapters, sections, subsections, table of contents are also bilingual

Tags: books

I would like to write a bilingual book (say, English and French). The only requirements are that

- The French text should be printed on the left-hand pages and the corresponding English translation printed on the right.
- The page numbers for both the left-hand as well as the right hand side should be same.

Since I have no idea how to do this, being a rather beginner in using TeX, in the answer, please provide an MWE. Here is my attempt,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
    
\mainmatter


\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}
    \ParallelLText{\selectlanguage{french} %
        \tableofcontents
        \part{}
        \chapter{}
        \section{}
        \subsection{}
    }
    \ParallelRText{ %
        \selectlanguage{english}
        \tableofcontents
        \part{}
        \chapter{}
        \section{}
       \subsection{}
    }

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you need to synchronise page breaks and/or section headings, eg if you have a section that lasts three pages with just text do you need to page break the two versions at the "same" place or just allow each to page break normally and just re-synchronise at the next forced page break? Similarly do section headings need to align since your example has no text of any sort it is rather hard to guess what is needed

Comment: In case of the first question it seems that for my purpose both will be required at some places. But currently I need the second one. In case of the second question, the section headings do need to align @DavidCarlisle.

Answer (score 4):

Might be a little bit late to answer but I will anyway (this may help someone esle)...

I like the way you try (or tried) to get a result, but after several unsuccessful attempts on my side, I selected another solution that is based on 3 (actually it can be 2 or more) columns (1 per language).
Here is the result. Hope it helps.

Enjoy!

Cheers!

[image]

[image]

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry} % Document margins and spacings

\usepackage[english, french, occitan]{babel}    % Multilingual support for LaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and Plain TeX
\usepackage{microtype}                          % Subliminal refinements towards typographical perfection
\usepackage{paracol}                            % Multiple columns with texts “in parallel”
\usepackage{lettrine}                           % Typeset dropped capitals
\usepackage{xcolor}                             % Driver-independent color extensions for LaTeX and pdfLaTeX
\usepackage{titlesec}                           % Select alternative section titles


\begin{document}

    \setlength{\columnsep}{5mm}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}
    \colseprulecolor{gray}
    
    \begin{paracol}{3}
            \input{chapter-1-trilingual}
        \end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

**chapter-1-trilingual.tex**

```
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\selectlanguage{english}
\paragraph{}
\hspace{0mm}\lettrine[lines=2]{S}{quire} Trelawney, Dr. Livesey, and the rest of these gentlemen having asked me to write down the whole particulars about Treasure Island, from the beginning to the end, keeping nothing back but the bearings of the island, and that only because there is still treasure not yet lifted, I take up my pen in the year of grace 17... and go back to the time when my father kept the Admiral Benbow inn and the brown old seaman with the sabre cut first took up his lodging under our roof.
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{french}
\paragraph{}
\hspace{0mm}\lettrine[lines=2]{C}{'est} sur les instances de M. le chevalier Trelawney, du docteur Livesey et de tous ces messieurs en général, que je me suis décidé à mettre par écrit tout ce que je sais concernant l’île au trésor, depuis A jusqu’à Z, sans rien excepter que la position de l’île, et cela uniquement parce qu’il s’y trouve toujours une partie du trésor. Je prends  donc  la  plume  en  cet  an  de  grâce  17...  et commence  mon  récit  à  l’époque  où  mon  père  tenait l’auberge  de  l’Amiral  Benbow,  en  ce  jour  où  le  vieux marin, au visage basané et balafré d’un coup de sabre, vint prendre gîte sous notre toit.
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{occitan}
\paragraph{}
\hspace{0mm}\lettrine[lines=2]{L}{o} squire Trelawney, lo doctor Livesey e los autres senhers m'encargueron d'escriure de pòst a fin sens omestre ren tot çò que se tracta sus l'illa del tresaur, levat la posicion geografica, que soi solide qu'existis encara un tresaur qu'es pas descobert... preni la pluma, donc l'an de gràcia de 17... e torni fins al temps que lo miu paire teniá l'alberga de l'Amiral Benbou e d'aquí al jorn ont lo marin vièlh de pèl abasanida, amb nafrada sus la gauta prenguèt lotjament sota nòstra teulada per la primièra fes.
\switchcolumn*
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\selectlanguage{english}
\paragraph{}
I remember him as if it were yesterday, as he came plodding to the inn door, his sea- chest following behind him in a hand-barrow — a tall, strong, heavy, nut-brown man, his tarry pigtail falling over the shoulder of his soiled blue coat, his hands ragged and scarred, with black, broken nails, and the sabre cut across one cheek, a dirty, livid white. I remember him looking round the cover and whistling to himself as he did so, and then breaking out in that old sea-song that he sang so often afterwards:
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{french}
\paragraph{}
Je me le rappelle, comme si c’était d’hier. Il arriva d’un  pas  lourd  à  la  porte  de  l’auberge,  suivi  de  sa cantine  charriée  sur  une  brouette. C’était  un  grand gaillard  solide,  aux  cheveux  très  bruns  tordus  en  une queue  poisseuse  qui  retombait  sur  le  collet  d’un  habit bleu  malpropre ;  il  avait  les  mains  couturées  de cicatrices, les ongles noirs et déchiquetés, et la balafre du coup de sabre, d’un blanc sale et livide, s’étalait en travers  de  sa  joue.  Tout  en  sifflotant,  il  parcourut  la crique  du  regard,  puis  de  sa  vieille  voix  stridente  et chevrotante  qu’avaient  rythmée  et  cassée  les manœuvres  du  cabestan,  il  entonna  cette  antique rengaine de matelot qu’il devait nous chanter si souvent par la suite : 
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{occitan}
\paragraph{}
Me remembri d'el coma s'èra d'ièr e lo vesi avançar d'un pesuc pas cap a la pòrta de l'albèrga amb son còfra de marin sus una bariòta que qualqu'un conduisiá. Èra un òme espatlut, bedre, vigorós que sos cabels brums davalan sus un catògan pegos de quitram e mai sas espatlas. lo siu mantèl blau èra solhat de bonhas. Sas mans amb onglas negras e trencadas èram rosegadas e cubertas de cretges. La nafra de sabre a travèrs sa pòta èra repugnanta e d'un blanc blau. Lo vesi encara percórrer amb lo regard la calanca tot en siblejar, puèi còp sec l'òme debutèt lo cant d'aquela canson de bèl temps a:
\switchcolumn*
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\selectlanguage{english}
\paragraph{}
\begin{center}
\textit{Fifteen men on the dead man’s chest\\
Yo-ho-ho, and a bottle of rum!} 
\end{center}
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{french}
\paragraph{}
\begin{center}
\textit{Nous étions quinze sur le coffre du mort...\\
Yo-ho-ho ! et une bouteille de rhum !} 
\end{center}
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{occitan}
\paragraph{}
\begin{center}
\textit{Son quinze los que vòlon lo còfre d'aquel mòrt...\\
Son quinze o! o! o! e me cal de rom mas del bon !}
\end{center}
\switchcolumn*
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\selectlanguage{english}
\paragraph{}
In the high, old tottering voice that seemed to have been tuned and broken at the capstan bars. Then he rapped on the door with a bit of stick like a handspike that he carried, and when my father appeared, called roughly for a glass of rum. This, when it was brought to him, he drank slowly, like a connoisseur, lingering on the taste and still looking about him at the cliffs and up at our signboard.
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{french}
\paragraph{}
Après  quoi,  de  son  bâton,  une  sorte  d’anspect,  il heurta contre la porte et, à mon père qui s’empressait, commanda  brutalement  un  verre  de  rhum.  Aussitôt servi, il le but posément et le dégusta en connaisseur, sans cesser d’examiner tour à tour les falaises et notre enseigne.
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{occitan}
\paragraph{}
Que tan sovent o entendiguèri cantar après, amb aquela votz forta e tremolanta que semblava èsser estada exercitada e petada dins las barras del cabestant. Quand l'òme semblet content de vistalhar, tustèt a la porta amb un baston que teniá a la man. Alara lo miu paire acorriguet e bruscament lo marin li demandèt un veire de rom. Après que foguèt servit, l'òme o tastèt, chuquèt pausadament per o saborar coma un coneisseire refastinhòs, mas espinchèt sens relambi siá las balses siá l'ensnha de l'alberga.
\switchcolumn*
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\selectlanguage{english}
\paragraph{}
– ``This is a handy cove,'' says he at length; ``and a pleasant sittyated grog-shop. Much company, mate?''
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{french}
\paragraph{}
– ``Voilà  une  crique  commode'',  dit-il  à  la  fin,  ``et  un cabaret  agréablement  situé.  Beaucoup  de  clientèle, camarade ?''
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{occitan}
\paragraph{}
– ``Es una cala de las bonas e de las mai prigondas'' çò diguèt ``e l'albèrga es plan emplaçada. O! l'amic! Fòrça candoliers praquí?''
\switchcolumn*
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\selectlanguage{english}
\paragraph{}
My father told him:\\
\indent– No, very little company, the more was the pity.
\indent– “Well, then,” said he, “this is the berth for me. Here you, matey,” he cried to the man who trundled the barrow; “bring up alongside and help up my chest. I’ll stay here a bit,” he continued. “I’m a plain man; rum and bacon and eggs is what I want, and that head up there for to watch ships off. What you mought call me? You mought call me captain. Oh, I see what you’re at — there”; and he threw down three or four gold pieces on the threshold. “You can tell me when I’ve worked through that,” says he, looking as fierce as a commander.
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{french}
\paragraph{}
Mon  père  lui  répondit  négativement:\\
\indent– Très  peu  de clientèle ; si peu que c’en était désolant.
\indent– Eh  bien !  alors,  reprit-il,  je  n’ai  plus  qu’à  jeter l’ancre... Hé ! l’ami, cria-t-il à l’homme qui poussait la brouette, accostez ici et aidez à monter mon coffre... Je resterai ici quelque temps, continua-t-il. Je ne suis pas difficile : du rhum et des œufs au lard, il ne m’en faut pas plus, et cette pointe là-haut pour regarder passer les bateaux.  Comment  vous  pourriez  m’appeler ?  Vous pourriez m’appeler capitaine... Ah ! je vois ce qui vous inquiète...  Tenez !  (Et  il  jeta  sur  le  comptoir  trois  ou quatre  pièces  d’or.)  Vous  me  direz  quand  j’aurai  tout dépensé,  fit-il,  l’air  hautain  comme  un  capitaine  de vaisseau.
\switchcolumn

\selectlanguage{occitan}
\paragraph{}
Mon paire li diguèt:\\
\indent-- Plan pauc e aquò es causa lanhosa!\\
\indent-- Aquò rai, faguèt l'òme, aquesta conca es çò que me cal. E tu, mòssi, cridèt a l'òme que tirava la bariòta que conteniá lo còfre de bord, acostas aicí e botas en naut aqueste afar! Vai demorar aicí un brave temps. E lambiardeja pas, que vòli de ròm, d'uòus cillats amb lardons e rabinels; aquò's tot çò que demandi e subretot aqueste pòst amondaut per susvelhar las naus a la larga.
\switchcolumn*
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

For correct justification, you may need to add **\sloppy**:

```
\begin{document}

    \sloppy

    \setlength{\columnsep}{5mm}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.2pt}
    \colseprulecolor{gray}
    
    \begin{paracol}{3}
            \input{chap/99-chap-1-MULTI}
        \end{paracol}

\end{document}
```